# _getch() misses some inputs in multi-thread program

Tags: multithreading, getch

I use `_getch()` in one thread of my multi-thread Windows console program, which is built with Visual C++. If I press a little faster, `_getch()` misses some inputs. For example, I enter a string `"hello"`, bug `_getch()` gets the characters `'h'`, `'l'`,`'l'`,`'o'`. It missed `'e'`. If I press a little slower, it gets all the characters. There are 6 threads altogether with a 3rdparty library.

If I do not use the 3rdparty library, there are 3 threads. Everything works OK.

So is there any possibility that 3rdparty code modifies the attribute of the console that leads the problem?

Comment: I forget to say that `_getch()` is in a loop to get multiple inputs.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt C++. And I want the input immediately, instead of an ENTER.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments. Also, as it stands, it is off topic because the instructions how to reproduce the behaviour are missing. Please refer to the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 3rdparty library, in another thread, is stealing keyboard inputs.